# Need help on XAML Grid formatting the wrong way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml page that formats exactly as I would expect it to.  The first two rows and the last row take up only the space that the elements allow for.  Then, the third row takes up the remaining space on the page.  Here is the xaml that works as expected:

```
<Grid>
    <!--Parent Grid-->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--Parent Row 0-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">           
        <Label  Content="Auto Row 0"></Label>            
    </Grid>
    <!--Parent Row 1-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
        <Label Content="Auto Row 1"></Label>
    </Grid>

    <!--Parent Row 2-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
        <Label Content="Stretch Row 2"></Label>
    </Grid>

    <!--Parent Row 3-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="5">
        <Label Content="Auto Row 3"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

However, this page is loaded into the first row of the following grid.  When it is loaded into this row, every row takes on the 'Auto' characteristic.  So, each row is not scrunched up next to the other instead of the third row taking up all remaining space on the page.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Controls:SettingsTabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="mytab"></Controls:SettingsTabControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <Controls:SettingsFooter Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Grid.Row="0" should be on the StackPanel

Comment: @Marco, it doesn't matter : if Row is not set , then it is defaulted to 0

Comment: Correct.  Moving it to the StackPanel has no effect

Comment: I can delete the SettingsFooter control completely along with the row that contains it and it has zero effect on my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a DockPanel instead of the Grid on the second part.

```
   <DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Controls:SettingsFooter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
        <Controls:SettingsTabControl x:Name="mytab" /> 
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: It works!  But, can you please explain WHY that fixed it?

Comment: DockPanel per Default has the property of letting the last child use all of the available space (u can turn it off). The grid will not - it's more complicated to get the same effect on the grid - that's why always when i can, i use dockpanel.